# Unable to find module 'uglifyjs-webpack-plugin', even with version 1.2.7

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have updated my package.json so that I am using uglifyjs-webpack-plugin 1.2.7.

> Error: Cannot find module 'uglifyjs-webpack-plugin'

I get the error when running the following build.

```
ng build --prod && ng run ModuleIssue:server:production && webpack --progress --colors
```

I have the following dependencies and devDependencies in my package.json.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "webpack": "^4.15.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.7"
  }
```

The complete package.json and angular.json can be found at https://github.com/jonasarcangel/ModuleIssue/tree/master/ClientApp

I don't know which package / version is causing this problem.

Comment: have you tried removing node_modules and package-lock.json, and running NPM install?

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you paste your webpack config file?

Comment: I don't think I have one. All the files are at https://github.com/jonasarcangel/ModuleIssue/tree/master/ClientApp

Comment: follow this guide: https://angular.io/guide/universal

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems to me that you're trying to add server side rendering, please follow this guide: angular.io/guide/universal